# MOODLE: Exception - Class not found

Tags: php, moodle

To modify an existing plugin and add a log with the event trigger,

I have the class in the folder as well as in the figure below:

[image]

I have added the code as follows:

```
$params = array(
            'context' => $this->world->get_context(),
            'relateduserid' =>      $USER->id,
        );
$lupevent = \block_xp\event\user_leaderboardview::create($params);
$lupevent->trigger();
```

I have also added a `user_leaderboardview.php`, inside

`classes\event` folder.

**user_leaderboardview**

```
<?php

namespace block_xp\event;
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class user_leaderboardview extends \core\event\base {

    public function get_description() {
        return 'The user witih ID ' . $this->userid . ' view the leaderboard .';
    }  
}
```

With these things done, however, I am getting the error as.

> Exception - Class 'block_xp\event\user_leaderboardview' not found

Where am I missing to add the configuration? Why is the class not found?

Is this the problem of the namespace? or server not loading the page?

Please help with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you purged the site caches or bumped the plugin version number (last digit only)? Moodle caches all autoloaded class names, so you need to clear the cache if you add a new class.

Comment: No! i have not purged the site cache... I just refresh and clear the browser cache.

Comment: `https://yoursite.com/admin/purgecaches.php`, did my job!

Answer (score 0):

Also if you faced with problem like `Uncaught Error: Class 'cache' not found` (or any another class):

1. Try to clear cache via cli command from Moodle root `php admin/cli/purge_caches.php`
2. **Check your php version** in nginx/apache config. It will happens if config has **old php version**, *for example* version 7, **but your Moodle follows to newer 8+ version**.